# How to mark that more information is needed for a resource in REST

Tags: java, rest

When creating a user we send the user information, create the user in the database (so now the user have uniqe id) and perform a credit check.

If a) the user has a credit score above a certain number everything is Ok (201). 
   b) If not we need more information from the User.

What would be the Restful way to deal with b.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still return an OK / HTTP status 200 or Created / 201. As far as I understand your question your new user will be created anyway and just the subsequent credit check might fail. But the server-side and the client-side worked as expected. This is the only important thing. You could only use a 4xx if something went wrong on the client side, e.g. the user used a string in a number field. You can't use a 5xx because nothing on the server side went wrong, e.g. your credit service had an exception. The actual information that your credit service failed and more information from the user is needed should go in the body of the HTTP response.

Comment: I think I was too fast in writing my own answer. Of course using `400` should not be used, if the action had a (partially) success. I removed my answer in favor of yours.

Comment: The granularity of the HTTP status codes isn't fine enough to map to more specific error messages. Like I suggested for everything more detailed you should put it in the body of the HTTP response, e.g. in a JSON object containing an additional error code or an error message.

Answer (score 2):

In its current form the credit check sounds more like an RPC operation than a RESTful resource. Although the credit check might invoke a REST API of some bank which returns `credit-worthy` or not as a result of a query, this is not very RESTful including the check into the user-creation process (IMO).

Therefore, b) is not really RESTful in the sense that it does not deal with resources but performs an RPC like action (the credit check).

You basically have two options here:

- define the whole process as atomic and declare credit properties as mandatory and create a user only if also his payment/credit/... options are available and checked positively (return 400 if something is missing or check failed)
- split the user creation from the credit-check

For the latter one, you should separate the credit check from the user-creation. On successfully creating a user, return 201 (as you do) with additional links clients can use to perform the next task (HATEOAS).

As the credit check itself is not a real good candidate for a RESTful service as it is not a resource per se but more of an RPC like action (as already annotated), you probably want to refactor this code into a maybe Spring managed service bean which you inject into these resource handlers which require a credit-worthy user.

You can furthermore provide a balance sheet (`/api/users/1234/balance`) where a user can look up his current balance and gain actions (in form of links) a user can use to proceed further (like adding more money to his balance and so on).

If f.e. a user tries to access `/api/article/yxz` and this article requires the user to have a positive balance, you could return a `402 Payment Required` in case the user has not enough money left.

Comment: I agree it's a good idea to split user creation from credit check. I'd disagree the credit check should be RPC. It could be as simple as a GET on user with some param, or if it's complex/asynchronous, it could be a POST to create a separate credit-check resource. (In practice, I believe most financial institutions would actually consider credit checks important enough activities to warrant their own archivable record.)

Comment: @mahemoff thanks for correcting my spelling :) I didn't say it has to be RPC, I just mentioned that it sounds more like old style RPC and I also gave an example at the beginning how a RESTful check-credit may look like - though, there is still the action performed for each user in reference to the OP - and this is what Roy Fielding argues about most "REST" services today out there, that they still behave RPC like.